# Is there an expression similar to "ugh" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

What do we use to show frustration in Esperanto texting/tweeting? In English, for example we would use, "ugh" or maybe "*sigh*"

Comment: I found it in the wiktionary, it's aĉ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According [to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a%C4%89), *aĉ* is an interjection used to "express dismay at a bad or unfortunate situation". They give the following example: *Aĉ, kion mi devas fari nun?* -> "Ugh, what am I supposed to do now?"

I have not heard this often, but to me it comes across as less intensely emotional as *ve*, which is defined by PMEG as "kordoloro aŭ bedaŭrego pro malfeliĉo", so it might be more appropriate in some situations.

Answer (score 11):

I think the best translation is *ve*; [*ho ve* is also used](http://esperanto.davidgsimpson.com/eo-interjections). Where *The Republic* of Plato might show [“Ah, woe is me!” in an English translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Plat.+Rep.+3.388&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0168#note-link7), its analog in Esperanto is [*Ve! Ve al mi!*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rBOyBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA88)

Answer (score 7):

In my experience I often heard – and thus often use ­– "*Fu!*" or "*Aĥ!*"